# How can I draw a mathematical function in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I want to set a particular bar as the **reference bar** (x = 0), and then use the relative bars to that reference point as argument for a mathematical function.

**Example**: I want to draw the function 5x + 3, so in the reference bar (x = 0) the value should be 3. And 7 bars in the future from the reference bar, the value should be 5*7 + 3 = 38. And 5 bars in the past from the reference bar, the value should be 5*(-5) + 3 = -22.

Of course, that mathematical function should be drawn for a **single** reference bar only  (the current bar, or any bar select through input). Otherwise, the screen would be filled with dozens of parallel lines ;)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the right (positive) part of the drawing:

```
//@version=4
study("")
barstart = input(0)
f = 5 * max(0, (bar_index - barstart)) + 3
plot(bar_index >= barstart ? f : na)
```

The drawing in the past on negative references can't be done, unless you use line drawings and are happy with a max of ~50 negative bars.

In Pine, you're drawing as you go, bar by bar; you can't just go back and forth on the x scale as you wish, except with [drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html).

[EDIT 2020.04.14 10:29 — LucF]

To use the close at bar 400 in further calcs, use:

```
var c = 0.
c := bar_index == 400 ? close : c
```

Comment: Do you also know how to make the Close value at one particular bar_index available for calculations all bars?

Comment: Added 2 lines at the end of the answer.